# F# DbContext Inheritance with multiple constructors and property

Tags: functional-programming, f#, entity-framework-core

I'm learning my way to using Ef Core in an F# project.
I'm inheriting the DbContext, and I just want a sense check. 
Is this a useful approach in the manner of F#? Using this method of inheritance, and having to explictly set the `connectionString` property? Would an explict primary constructor been more idiomatic for this?

```
type TestDbContext =
     inherit DbContext

     new (conn:string) = {inherit DbContext(); connectionString = Some conn}
     new (opts:DbContextOptions<TestDbContext>) = {inherit DbContext(opts); connectionString = None}
     val connectionString:Option<string>
     member x.ConnectionString
      with get() = match x.connectionString with
                 | Some con -> con
                 | None -> ""

    override __.OnConfiguring (options) = 
       if not(options.IsConfigured) then
         options.UseSqlServer(__.ConnectionString) |>ignore
    override __.OnModelCreating modelBuilder = modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(TemplateDbBuilder()) |> ignore
```

Comment: Is usability of the assembly from C# important to you?

Comment: No this is all about f# and how to interact with .Net ecosystem.